# Chevrolet cruze 2011 code 82?

Tags: chevrolet, oil, oil-change, cruze

I have a Cruze 2011, and I recently changed the oil, now the car is showing Code 82, I checked on the internet and seems to be related to oil
I take out the yellow stick to check the oil level and the oil seems to be dark in my opinion.
When I changed the oil on Canadian Tire (I assume that they don't put on my car used oil "like a scam I said") they said to me that will change the oil for a synthetic one, that is better I heard,
It's the synthetic oil more dark?. 
It's the car showing the code 82 because of bad oil?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was the code showing before you changed the oil or only after? Have you tried resetting the code (which can be done through the turn signal stalk)?

Comment: Started showing a week ago, and I changed oil two month ago

Comment: I saw a video on youtube of how to do it , I will check that

Comment: So Every time I change the oil I need to do a reset info on the car menu?

Comment: Yes, every time. There are multiple ways to reset the oil change light either with the turn signal stalk and the DIC or a button pad on the right side of the steering wheel or KOEO press the gas pedal three times.

Comment: What's the recommended amount of Km to change the oil (synthetic oil)on this car model (Cruze 2011 with more than 120 000 km ran)? , I'm already 4200 Km since I changed the oil?

Comment: According to [this maintenance schedule for a 2012](https://my.chevrolet.com/content/dam/gmownercenter/gmna/dynamic/manuals/2012/chevrolet/cruze/2012%20Chevrolet%20Cruze.pdf), you should change it out about every 12kkm (7500 miles).